# Show that his cover does not have any finite sub covers

Tags: analysis, proof-writing

My question is **how to prove that the following cover does not have a finite sub cover** :

$$A_{n}=\{x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}: \frac{1}{2n}<|x|<\frac{3}{2n} \}$$

for the pointed ball $B_1^*(x) = \{ x: 0 < |x| \le 1 \}$

But the thing is how can I prove it because I don't know is there is a standard method to do it or how do I have to proceed, I think that this has to be easy, but I need your help :) thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $U = \{ A_i \mid i \ J \}$ is a subcover, where $J$ is a set of integers. Every subcover can be written this way: you just include in $J$ the indices of all the "A"-sets that are included.

If $J$ were finite, then it has a maximum (every finite set of integers has a maximum element); class this maximum $N$. Then the point  $(\frac{1}{4N}, 0, \ldots, 0)$, is not covered by $U$. Why not? Suppose that it were. Then for some $i \in J$, we'd have
$$
\frac{1}{2i} < \frac{1}{4N} < \frac{3}{2i}
$$
Ignoring the second inequality, this says that

$$
\frac{1}{2i} < \frac{1}{4N} \\
2i > 4N \\
i > 2N
$$
But since $N$ is the maximum of a set of positive integers, it's positive. Hence $2N > N$, so we conclude $i > N$, which is a contradiction, since $N$ was defined to be the largest element of $J$.

(By the way, the letter $n$ is used for two different things in this problem. (1) the dimension of the space $\mathbb R^n$, and (2) an index for elements of an open cover. I suggest replacing the first use by $k$.)

Comment: thanks for the help, do you mean to take R^k or something ?

Comment: And well it won't right because 1/4n is lower than 1/2N with N the larger N right ?

Comment: i am sorry it won't  be less than 3\2n right?

Comment: (1). Yes,  replace $\mathbb R^n$ with $\mathbb R^k$ in the def'n of $A_n$. (2) Yes, your reasoning is correct: that point of the ball will not be covered by your finite "subcover" (i.e., the subcover isn't actually actually a cover...it's just a sub*set* of a cover. (3) I have no idea what your last comment about $\frac{3}{2n}$ is asking.

Comment: well that the reason of why it won't cover that point is because  
i am sorry it won't be less than 3\2n right?

Comment: I believe you should draw a picture of $A_n$, which is an annulus (a "ring"). When you do, it'll be clear that the point I wrote down is in the hollow region *inside* the ring, i..e, that $\frac{1}{4n} <\frac{1}{2n}$. It's also within the outer circle of the annulus ($|x| = \frac{3}{2n}$), but that's really not important.

Comment: ok then the reason I because 1/4n<1/2N with N the maximum n right

Comment: Yes. That's right.

Comment: well but the thing is that 1/2N is almost zero and 1/4n is not almost zero :), I confused in that part

Comment: I'll rewrite my answer slightly to clarify.

Comment: thank you I will appreciate that

Comment: well I think J os for naturals isn't ?